# Template specialisation where parameter is non-type parameterized template for metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have the following code:

```
template<int lengthAfter>
class VariableString{
    public:
        enum{
            fieldSize = -1000
        };

....

};

template<typename T, int FieldSize = sizeof(T)>
class field_trait{
    public:
        enum{
            fieldSize = FieldSize
        };

....
};

template<int lengthAfter>
class field_trait<VariableString<lengthAfter>, -1000>{
    public:
        enum{
            fieldSize = -1000
        };
....
};

static_assert(field_trait<VariableString<0> >::fieldSize == -1000, "VariableString length error");
```

When I compile, the `static_assert` fails where I would expect the specialisation to work. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specialization is only good for the second argument of -1000,  but it is `sizeof(first argument)`  as the default in the main template says. That is, your invocation is really equivalent to

field_trait, sizeof (VariableString<0>)>

Do this

```
template<int lengthAfter, int size>
   class field_trait<VariableString<lengthAfter>, size>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the size parameter needs to be fixed. In final usage, field_trait is passed only VariableString<0> as a parameter from another template. There is no place that a size parameter can be injected.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. You change the specialization, not the usage. See http://ideone.com/JNrojd

Comment: Just tried the example code you posted. It works. I see what you mean now.